# concatenating dataframes based on pre-existing rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

I have the following function which makes an initial DataFrame, iterates over a dict of functions and concatenates a dataframe to the initial one with each iteration:

```
def get_variables_daily(start_date='1990-06-08', end_date='2015-05-04', describe=False):

variables_daily = {"DP": [1, get_DP_daily], "PE": [1, get_PE_daily], "BM": [1, get_BM_daily], "CAPE": [1, get_CAPE_daily], 
         "PCAprice": [1, get_PCAprice_daily], "BY": [1, get_BY_daily], "DEF": [1, get_DEF_daily],
         "TERM": [1, get_TERM_daily], "CAY": [1, get_CAY_daily], "SIM": [1, get_SIM_daily], "VRP": [1, get_VRP_daily], 
         "IC": [0, get_IC_daily], "BDI": [1, get_BDI_daily], "NOS": [1, get_NOS_daily], "CPI": [1, get_CPI_daily],
         "PCR": [1, get_PCR_daily], "MA": [1, get_MA_daily],  "PCAtech": [0, get_PCAtech_daily], 
         "OIL": [1, get_OIL_daily], "SI": [1, get_SI_daily]}

    start_date = pd.to_datetime(start_date, yearfirst=True)
    end_date = pd.to_datetime(end_date, yearfirst=True)
    #create initial timeseries
    SPXR_1M = get_SPXR_daily(22, '1990-06-08', '2015-05-04')
    SPXR_3M = get_SPXR_daily(65, '1990-06-08', '2015-05-04')
    SPXR_6M = get_SPXR_daily(130, '1990-06-08', '2015-05-04')
    SPXR_12M = get_SPXR_daily(252, '1990-06-08', '2015-05-04')

    df1 = pd.concat([SPXR_1M, SPXR_3M, SPXR_6M, SPXR_12M], axis=1)
    #iterate over variables
    for key in variables_daily.keys():
        #check if variable should be used
        check = variables_daily[key][0]
        if check == 1:
            df2 = variables_daily[key][1](start_date, end_date).convert_objects(convert_numeric=True) 
            df1 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)                                   
    return df
```

As you can see, SPXR_1M, SPXR_3M, SPXR_6M, and SPXR_12M are my base for the DataFrame, meaning I should have NO more rows than SPXR_1M should have. However, if you look at the summary of the final DF:

```
            count       mean       std        min        25%        50%  \
DP         5706.0   0.018063  0.004894   0.008400   0.014900   0.017900   
PE         6497.0  19.750139  4.267477  10.949800  16.581000  18.395300   
BM         6497.0   0.371955  0.088411   0.192378   0.323687   0.369440   
CAPE       6275.0  25.824579  6.981803  11.849780  20.973447  24.878816   
PCAprice   5706.0  -3.125544  3.082865 -17.258065  -4.958795  -2.354091   
BY         6249.0   0.977558  0.105177   0.566707   0.915942   0.972425   
DEF        6231.0   0.954645  0.413315   0.430000   0.700000   0.870000   
TERM       6485.0   1.865422  1.158198  -0.989000   0.916300   1.994900   
CAY        6275.0   0.000324  0.016228  -0.031944  -0.012895  -0.002148   
SIM        6252.0   0.742821  0.324054   0.007692   0.484615   0.976923   
VRP        6272.0   0.066305  0.038604  -0.141507   0.042648   0.059513   
BDI        6246.0   0.044917  0.324404  -0.900719  -0.133461   0.012865   
NOS        6191.0   0.010533  0.043129  -0.193359  -0.011152   0.010640   
CPI        6275.0   0.023318  0.011918  -0.020422   0.016667   0.024161   
PCR        6275.0  -1.361110  0.363751  -2.260664  -1.609558  -1.412000   
MA         6497.0   0.769432  0.421229   0.000000   1.000000   1.000000   
OIL        6252.0   0.012821  0.179430  -1.132002  -0.079546   0.029171   
SI         2226.0   3.689411  0.744130   1.952062   3.182868   3.719568   
SPXR_22D   6253.0   0.007297  0.045672  -0.297937  -0.016283   0.010915   
SPXR_65D   6210.0   0.022014  0.076810  -0.409638  -0.013432   0.028260   
SPXR_130D  6145.0   0.046397  0.113950  -0.474598  -0.003915   0.055771   
SPXR_252D  6023.0   0.091534  0.169579  -0.488228   0.028048   0.110181   

                 75%        max  
DP          0.020300   0.040000  
PE         23.155400  30.720600  
BM          0.437982   0.688610  
CAPE       27.720910  47.255292  
PCAprice   -0.651261   0.001848  
BY          1.042780   1.457659  
DEF         1.050000   3.500000  
TERM        2.793000   3.863000  
CAY         0.012844   0.031044  
SIM         1.000000   1.000000  
VRP         0.082342   0.372942  
BDI         0.196221   2.320175  
NOS         0.033015   0.253546  
CPI         0.029222   0.059571  
PCR        -1.140890  -0.333101  
MA          1.000000   1.000000  
OIL         0.119024   0.771293  
SI          4.202039   5.760021  
SPXR_22D    0.033889   0.224057  
SPXR_65D    0.067303   0.388187  
SPXR_130D   0.112865   0.541292  
SPXR_252D   0.200745   0.685735
```

You can see that the observations are not consistent, while they should essentially all be 6253 or a little less if they have less rows. Is my concatenation not handling extra rows in the appended dataframes properly?
EDIT: It seems like there are many gaps in my initial columns after all the concatenations. Is there any way to make panda only add rows from dataframe B that dataframe A already has?

Comment: What is `variables_daily`? a global variable? Also - why not clean your code to a MWE, eg remove prints and `corr` calculation which obfuscate the original problem with `df` frame?

Comment: My mistake, did not paste the MWE. variables_daily is simply a dict with T/F:function pairs, so I can check which variables I want to get. The post now has the dict in the function

Comment: This can (since you have unequal numbers for observations) only be achieved if you have some sort of index. E.g. an `id` for each row or something like a timestamp. Do you have something like that?

Comment: How silly of me, I forgot to mention that this is all daily data, so yes, a timestamp associated with each row. The whole DF is one big timeseries being grown 1 variable at a time

Comment: In this case something like `df1.set_index('time').join(df2.set_index('time'), how='inner')` should do it. Btw if you refer to somebody in the comment section use @<username> - otherwise the user does not get a notification.

Comment: @StefanFalk aware of this, unfortunately one of my machines have some kind of issue that doesn't let me do it properly. Regardless, is this solution any different from a left-merge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got severla thoughts:

- `pd.concat` will mix the dataframe indicies and produce NA for the missing values, try setting `join=inner` parameter
- if you can reorganise data creation by column - might try also `merge` instead https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html, likely you need left merge
- do not shut the NA values with `.dropna()` - they may reveal which extra rows are inserted
- try shutting the second concat call - so that you can decide which of the two  is causing trouble

Comment: join='inner' reduces the count significantly, and deletes original rows from the dataframe. I believe merge is no different than an intersection. I removed dropna, and I'm 100% sure it is the second concat causing the trouble.

Comment: There is quite a few things going on in the second concat, which are not traceable. Why not rearrange the code to create columns then? They are much easier to inspect.

Comment: Well, each variable is on the exact same timespan, however since these are financial variables, they are not reported on the same days and due to holidays and many other reasons they are not all perfectly aligned. My idea was to have my SPXR_ND columns be a base, and to simply append whatever timespan-values I have that match the pre-existing timestamps in the DF.

Comment: Generate new variables by column and left-merge to base dataframe?

Comment: I'm not sure what it means to "generate variables by column", although I do believe I understand a left-merge